# Singularity classification of $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-7)^{2}}+\sin\frac{1}{z-7}$ at $z=7$

Tags: complex-analysis

I used the Laurent series to see that it has infinite terms with negatives at the exponent so it's an essential singularity, but I got a theorem in class which says that $z_{0}$ is a pole iff $$\lim_{z\,\rightarrow\,z_{0}} f(z)=\infty.$$ And I'm confused because when I study $$\lim_{z\,\rightarrow\,7}\frac{1}{(z-7)^{2}}+\sin\frac{1}{z-7}$$ I get that limit values $\infty$, what I guess it's wrong and the limit may oscillate in any way so the limit does not exist and also isn't $\infty$.

So if anyone could help me with that it would be so helpful.

Comment: How did you seem to get that "limit values ∞" ?

Comment: Revising my work it seems I wrote $\sin\frac{1}{\infty}$ instead of $\sin\frac{1}{0}$ while evaluating the limit and was just taking it as $\infty + 0$, just a mere confussion so I'm closing this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hesitation is correct: the sine term does not go to $\infty$ as $z \to 7$. A simple way to check this is to consider how $\sin \frac{1}{w}$ behaves as $w \to 0$ along the positive real axis.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm saying the limit does _not_ equal $\infty$, for precisely the reason @DanyWose hinted at (the oscillation of the sine).

Comment: Sorry, meant to comment to the original post.